# ASP.net 4.0 Routing not working with main domain name

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, asp.net-routing

I have a simple routing for my website news section. Routing works fine for almost all URL's like

http://www.abc.com/Default.aspx

http://www.abc.com/Default.aspx?PageId=3

http://www.abc.com/Latest-News-Details.aspx?PageID=28&NewsID=39

Problem only happens when i try to access website with **http://www.abc.com** for some reason it redirects it to the custom error page, I am not able track error to source & i cant generate any such error on my localhost.

Code sample

global.asx file

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs on application startup
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    //RouteDebug.RouteDebugger.RewriteRoutesForTesting(RouteTable.Routes);
}


public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.Ignore("{*allaspx}", new { allaspx = @".*\.aspx(/.*)?" });
    routes.Ignore("{*allcss}", new { allcss = @".*\.css(/.*)?" });
    routes.Ignore("{*alljpg}", new { alljpg = @".*\.jpg(/.*)?" });
    routes.Ignore("{*alljs}", new { alljs = @".*\.js(/.*)?" });
    routes.Add(new System.Web.Routing.Route("{resource}.css/{*pathInfo}", new System.Web.Routing.StopRoutingHandler()));
    routes.Add(new System.Web.Routing.Route("{resource}.js/{*pathInfo}", new System.Web.Routing.StopRoutingHandler()));

    ////For News
    routes.MapPageRoute("NewsRoute", "{NewsID}/{PageID}/{NewsTitle}", "~/Latest-News-Details.aspx", false,
         new RouteValueDictionary {
                    { "NewsID", "0" },
                    { "PageID", "0"},
                    { "NewsTitle", "event-not-found" }},
         new RouteValueDictionary {   
                    { "NewsID", "[0-9]{1,8}" },
                    { "PageID", "[0-9]{1,8}" }
                }); 
}
```

Right now i have disabled routing for News Section still it generates error if i leave the above routes  code un-commented .

I am not sure what is causing the problem.

how can i handle root for default domain like http://www.abc.com

I would appreciate help in this regards

Comment: do you have default document set in IIS?

Comment: It works if routing is disabled, i think problem is with path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved issue by creating another route to handle http://www.abc.com

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.Ignore("{*allaspx}", new { allaspx = @".*\.aspx(/.*)?" });
    routes.Ignore("{*allcss}", new { allcss = @".*\.css(/.*)?" });
    routes.Ignore("{*alljpg}", new { alljpg = @".*\.jpg(/.*)?" });
    routes.Ignore("{*alljs}", new { alljs = @".*\.js(/.*)?" });
    routes.Add(new System.Web.Routing.Route("{resource}.css/{*pathInfo}", new System.Web.Routing.StopRoutingHandler()));
    routes.Add(new System.Web.Routing.Route("{resource}.js/{*pathInfo}", new System.Web.Routing.StopRoutingHandler()));

    routes.MapPageRoute(
         "HomeRoute",
         "",
         "~/Default.aspx"
     );

    ////For News
    routes.MapPageRoute("NewsRoute", "{NewsID}/{PageID}/{NewsTitle}", "~/Latest-News-Details.aspx", false,
         new RouteValueDictionary {
                    { "NewsID", "0" },
                    { "PageID", "0"},
                    { "NewsTitle", "News-not-found" }},
         new RouteValueDictionary {   
                    { "NewsID", "[0-9]{1,8}" },
                    { "PageID", "[0-9]{1,8}" }
                }); 
}
```

It is strange for me as same routing working for other website with creating another rount to handle such request `http://www.abc.com`